# ASP.NET MVC Identity with SQL Server and Azure AD SSO for Authentication

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, single-sign-on

Does anyone have any knowledge of whether it is possible to implement an ASP.NET MVC website that uses Identity for authentication with both SQL Server user accounts and Azure AD?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sure someone does, yes, but what are *you* actually asking?

Comment: I'm asking for confirmation that it's possible as I can't find anything referenced...and I figure if I'm really lucky someone might point me to somewhere that provides info about how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible. Please take a look to [Configure and manage Azure AD authentication with Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell) and [Tutorial: Secure Azure SQL Database connection from App Service using a managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi).

Comment: Thanks Alfredo. Appreciate the guidance. Just to clarify I use my own SQL Server instance configured for Identity currently for authentication on the ASP.NET MVC website. A client who wishes to use this ASP.NET MVC website wants to use their own Azure AD service rather than have to create user accounts in my SQL Server.

Comment: The existing accounts will still authenticate as they currently do via user accounts in my SQL Server instance, but the new client will use SSO via their Azure AD.

Comment: @ledragon so a client that uses your MVC app would like to use their own SQL instance? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi, sorry missed this reply. Not their own SQL Instance, their own Azure AD service. But the rest of the users will still use our internal Identity SQL Server instance. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I created a solution for this case, that I feel is a good solution for authenticating users by user/pass and adding another option for login with Azure AD.

Initially, I implemented `Identity` in my project. I believe that you can create this with your Visual Studio templates.

After all `Identity` configurations are implemented, I go to add Azure AD `OpenIdConnect` instances and options. Its implementation is External Logins with Microsoft Account. (Note this block for personal account if your app registration is created in Azure AD).

It is very important to configure your app registration in Azure Portal with Web Platform and redirect URLs:
`https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc`
and
`https://localhost:5001/`

Follow my startup code:

```csharp
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });

    #region Microsoft SSO
    // Please read readme.md to understand Microsoft SSO configuration.
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ExternalLogin:Microsoft:ClientId");
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ExternalLogin:Microsoft:ClientSecret");
            options.CallbackPath = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ExternalLogin:Microsoft:CallbackPath");
        });
    #endregion

    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

And my `Configure` method to add all items for pipeline.

```csharp
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseSession();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```